# Error condition, how to implement it?

Tags: c, sorting

So what my codes does at the moment is quite simple. It receives an input like this:

```
5 4
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

The first line of the input represents the number of Ids and the number of relations. The following line are those relations. The program sorts these pairs, for example: 1 comes before 2, 2 comes before 3 and so on. In this case the outup will be 1 2 3 4 5.

In case of contradictive input, such as:

```
4 4
1 2
2 3
3 2
3 4
```

It returns "Incoerente".

My current problem is my input is "non conclusive" such as:

```
4 4
1 2
3 1
3 4
4 2
```

In this case the program doesnt really know where to place the 4 (after or before the 1?). My program right now (with the input above) will print "3 1 2", and ignores the 4 for some reason. When this situation apears I want to print "OTHERERROR".

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

void create_graph();
void add(int vertex);
int del();
int isEmpty();
int find_indegree_of_vertex(int vertex);

int total_vertices;
int adjacent_matrix[MAX][MAX];
int queue[MAX];
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
FILE *myFile;

int main(){

    myFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    int i;
    int numberArray[2];

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &numberArray[i]);

    int N = numberArray[0];
    int L = numberArray[1];

    int vertex, count, topological_sort[MAX], indegree[MAX];
    create_graph(N, L);

    for(i = 0; i < total_vertices; i++){
        indegree[i] = find_indegree_of_vertex(i);                       
        if(indegree[i] == 0){
            add(i);
        }
    }
    count = 0;
    while(!isEmpty() && count < total_vertices){
        vertex = del();
        topological_sort[++count] = vertex;
        for(i = 0; i < total_vertices; i++){
            if(adjacent_matrix[vertex][i] == 1){
                if(adjacent_matrix[i][vertex] == 1){
                    printf("INCOERENTE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
                }
                adjacent_matrix[vertex][i] = 0;
                indegree[i] = indegree[i] - 1;
                if(indegree[i] == 0){
                    add(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(count < total_vertices){
        printf("Incoerente\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Topological Order of Vertices\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        printf("%3d", topological_sort[i]+1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void add(int vertex){
    if(rear == MAX - 1){
        printf("Queue Overflow\n");
    }
    else{
        if (front == -1) {
            front = 0;
        }
        rear = rear + 1;
        queue[rear] = vertex ;
    }
}

int isEmpty(){
    if(front == -1 || front > rear ){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int del(){
    int element;
    if (front == -1 || front > rear){
        printf("Queue Underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        element = queue[front];
        front = front+1;
        return element;
    }
}

int find_indegree_of_vertex(int vertex){
    int count, total_indegree = 0;
    for(count = 0; count < total_vertices; count++){
        if(adjacent_matrix[count][vertex] == 1){
            total_indegree++;
        }
    }
    return total_indegree;
}

void create_graph(int N, int L){
    int count, maximum_edges, origin_vertex, destination_vertex;
    total_vertices = N;
    maximum_edges = L;
    int integers[MAX];
    int i =0;
    int num;

    while(fscanf(myFile, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        integers[i] = num;
        i++;
    }

    i=0;
    printf("1a linha :%d %d\n", N, L);

    for(count = 1; count <= maximum_edges; count++){

        origin_vertex = integers[i]-1;

        destination_vertex = integers[i+1]-1;

        printf("pares a ser avaliados :%d %d\n", origin_vertex+1, destination_vertex+1);

        if(origin_vertex > total_vertices || destination_vertex > total_vertices || origin_vertex < 0 || destination_vertex < 0){
            printf("Edge Co-ordinates are Invalid\n");
            count--;
        }
        else
            adjacent_matrix[origin_vertex][destination_vertex] = 1;

        if(count == maximum_edges){
            break;
        }

        i+=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could look up [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on WIkipedia, for exampe.  What you're dealing with is standard problem with topological sorts.